# How I can solve a problem with input size in a keras model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have created a model with the functional API with

```
shape = (128,128,1)
input = Input(shape=shape)
print(input.shape)
x = Conv2D(8,kernel_size=(7,7),padding="valid",name='input_conv'
  ,activation='relu')(input)
```

etc...

the shape have the expected size, the model summary shows

```
Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_1 (InputLayer)        [(None, 128, 128, 1)]     0         
                                                                 
 input_conv (Conv2D)         (None, 122, 122, 8)       400
```

I can fit and save the model. When I load the model and try to make a prediction with

```
print(f'''image shape {im.shape} {type(im)}''')
p = model.predict(im)
```

I get the error

```
image shape (128, 128, 1) <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
.
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 128, 128, 1) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 128, 128, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_1'), name='input_1', description="created by layer 'input_1'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (32, 128, 1, 1).
```

im is a numpy array with (128,128,1) so I can't figure out where (32, 128, 1, 1) is coming from.

Thanks

Very sorry, problem between chair and keyboard.

```
p = model.predict(im.reshape(1,128,128,1))
```

Solved the thing.

Answer (score 0):

32 is the batch size. You need to add one more dimension before predicting since the model expects batches of images. So you need to send a batch of a single image:

```py
import numpy as np

print(f'''image shape {im.shape} {type(im)}''')


p = model.predict(np.expand_dims(im, 0))
```

Comment: Looks like more elegant than my solution. Will try it

Comment: Be careful when using reshape. I personally tend to avoid it since some times it behaves unexpectedly.